# @IBDesignable within framework not work in storyboard

Tags: ios, frameworks, runtime, uistoryboard, swift2

I moved a custom control to my custom framework lib (Cocoa Touch Framework):

```
import UIKit  
@IBDesignable public class MyButton: UIButton {  
    public let DefaultBGColor = UIColor(red:40.0/255.0, green:120.0/255.0, blue:210.0/255.0, alpha:0.6)  
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius:CGFloat = 6 {  
        didSet{  
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius  
            self.setNeedsDisplay()  
        }  
    }  
}
```

I included successifully the Library to my App project

Now in the storyboard I tried to use it, but setting the customClass I notice that :

- within the Identity Inspector tab the module field is not filled and designable label is not present. neither the user runtime attribute.
- within the Attribute Inspector tab I don't see my custom property.
- at runtime I have a message: **Unknown class MyButton in Interface Builder file** that bloc the execution of my app

how can I solve it?

Have I to do something compiling my Framework?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm now experiencing the same issue.

Comment: not yet. I continued without this approach